# Django | Execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, django

Al ejecutar la insert sql, me devuelve el siguiente error. Al hacer una sola insert hace perfecto, pero al concatenar varios valores me devuelve el siguiente error:
¿Es posible que esté mal la manera de concatenar %s, %s, %s?
Gracias.

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**View:**

```
...
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = ''' 
                INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user,modality,numberQuestion,correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion,wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion) 
                VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) 
         '''
        cursor.execute(query, [userAnswer],[modalityPost],[numberQuestionPost],[ansOK],[ansWrong])
        print("Insert completo")
...
```

**Model:**

```
class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    numberQuestion = models.IntegerField('Número pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta correctamente',null=True,blank=True)
    wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta incorrectamente',null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los valores a reemplazar tienen que ir dentro de una sola lista, no elemento por lista. Intenta cambiarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
cursor.execute(query, [userAnswer, modalityPost, numberQuestionPost, ansOK, ansWrong])
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Lo siguiente: query = '''INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user,modality,numberQuestion,correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion,wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''' Me devuelve el siguiente error:  ProgrammingError at /test/saveUserAnswer
syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user,modality,numberQuestio... (señala con el símbolo ^ bajo la tabla testapp_useranswers. ¿Qué puede ser? Gracias.

Comment: De nada. Mmm. Es raro. Parece que eso está bien. Igual es una línea anterior o posterior la del error. Mira línea por línea bien y compara con otras consultas.